# Filter Leaflet markers by input selection in R Flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard, r-leaflet

I am trying to filter the markers that are drawn on a Leaflet map based on what is selected in a user defined date range. The below codes is returning an error that it is unable to find hfxLoc object. I have used the below approach (filtering within the *render*  function in other elements (i.e. renderPlot, renderValueBox, etc.). Is my approach to filtering correct, or does it need to occur in a different place in the Leaflet code block?

The inputSelect code is as follows:

```
selectizeInput("shiptypeInput", "Vessel type: ", choices = hfxVessels, selected = "Cargo ships", multiple = TRUE)
```

The leaflet code is as follows:

```
renderLeaflet({
  hfxLoc <- hfxETA %>%
    dplyr::filter(as.Date(eta_date) >= input$dateRange[1] & as.Date(eta_date) <=  input$dateRange[2]) %>%
  leaflet(data = hfxLoc) %>% 
  setView(lng = -60.25, lat = 46, zoom = 6) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron,
                   options = providerTileOptions(minZoom = 2, maxZoom = 16)) %>%
  addMarkers(lng = ~lon, lat = ~lat, clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
```

Comment: Could you try removing `data = hfxLoc` from `leaflet` - instead just call `leaflet()` without any arguments? Looks like you're already piping in the filtered data as the first argument already.

Comment: Thank you Ben that worked! Such an easy fix, can't believe I overlooked that, thanks again! Add it as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `data = hfxLoc` from `leaflet`, as you are already piping in the filtered data from the `filter` results. The piped-in resultant data will be assumed the first argument `data` in `leaflet`.

```
renderLeaflet({
  hfxLoc <- hfxETA %>%
    dplyr::filter(as.Date(eta_date) >= input$dateRange[1] & as.Date(eta_date) <=  input$dateRange[2]) %>%
    leaflet() %>%
    ...
```